# Create a ReadOnly log file with Log4Net

Tags: c#, log4net, readonly

I'm developing application in c# that creates 2 log files (.txt files): one for errors and another for modifications made by users. This two files are created with *log4net*. The issue I see is that this files can be edited, and so altered by mistake.

I would like to set this files to readonly, and that log4net still could write on them. Because if I just change the property in the file, the next log wont be written.

There is a way to do that?

Also, the user of the app can open this logs file from within the app. For that I use the next code:

```
System.IO.FileInfo finfo = new System.IO.FileInfo("path");
if (finfo.Exists)
{
 //finfo.Attributes = System.IO.FileAttributes.ReadOnly; 
 // I don't use the previous line at the moment, because it blocks the followings logs.
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path");
}
```

And this is the code to create and call the logger:

```
public static class CLogger
{
   private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CLogger));

   static CLogger()
   {
      XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo("path to .config file"));
   }

   public static void WriteLog(ELogLevel logLevel, String log)
   {
      if (logLevel.Equals(ELogLevel.DEBUG))
      {
         logger.Debug(log);
      }
      else if (logLevel.Equals(ELogLevel.ERROR))
            .
            .
            .          
      else if (logLevel.Equals(ELogLevel.WARN))
      {
                logger.Warn(log);
      }
   }
}
```

Calling to the logger:

```
CLogger.WriteLog(ELogLevel.ERROR, ex.ToString());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a ReadOnly log file with Log4Net AND Separate log in 2 files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117927/create-a-readonly-log-file-with-log4net-and-separate-log-in-2-files)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if the application runs under the rights of the user, than the user ultimately must have the rights to access the files: if he doesn't, the application wouldn't be able to write into this files either.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the rights on the folder where the logs are being written. The web server granted Read/Write, all other only Read.

Comment: If it is a web server application, then you'Re right. But the major question for me would be then: Why does a user have access to the web server?

Comment: I agree on that question, I tried to provide a quick solution to the problem.

Comment: @Sascha, @Niklas Ringdahl: It is an application in a internal network, so the .config file and the created log files are in a Network path. But if the files stay as read/write everyone could modify them by mistake. And if they are Read only, the application could not write more logs.

Comment: Under which account is the application running? The user or a system account?

Comment: The application checks the windows user login to determine if the user is or not allowed to start the application. But once the application is open, the code to access the file is the one above (log4net)